# show that $\int_{C_R} \frac{z e^{iz}}{1+z^2}dz$ tends to zero

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Show that $\int_{C_R} \frac{z e^{iz}}{1+z^2}dz$ where $C_R$ is the half circle in the upper half plane with radius $R$ tends to $0$ as $R$ goes to infinity.

My professor showed me something with Jordans Lemma here but I can't really remember what he did. Why can't I do it just like this:

$$
\left| \int_{C_R} \frac{z e^{iz}}{1+z^2}dz\right|≤ \int_{C_R} \frac{\left| z e^{iz} \right|}{\left|z^2\right|-1} \left|dz\right|≤
$$

{Now for $\left| e^{iz} \right|≤1$ in the upper half plane so we have that}

$$
≤ \frac{R}{R^2-1}
$$

and this goes clearly to zero as $R$ goes to infinity.

What have I missed?

Comment: You've forgotten the $\int_{C_R}|dz|\le \pi R$ term.

Comment: Yes now when you mention it, remember something about that! Can you explain?

Comment: You've only bounded the integrand (also, you want $R^2-1$ not $R^2+1$) but then the integral is bounded by

$$\int_{C_R}{R\over R^2-1}|dz|={\pi R^2\over R^2-1}$$

which goes to $\pi$ not $0$.

Comment: You have found an upper bound for the integrand function, but the measure of the integration domain depends on $R$, too.

Comment: My book only throws that $\pi R$ factor on, but I can't see where it comes from. Maybe you can show me. At least now I know where the problem is :) My final exam on this course is tomorrow so i'm trying to sort these final parts.

Comment: Oh never mind! It's the L in ML inequality, haha. Now I get it. Im going to ask one more thing before I close this. When you use jordans lemma (as I need to do here), do you ever prove it or is it enough to write it down and say that you are using it?

Comment: Would you need to close it? Maybe it can help someone?

Comment: I don't mean close it like take it away, just close the problem and move on.

Comment: What was the problem with my answer?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492726/compute-int-0-infty-fracx-sin-x1x2dx-with-the-residue-theorem

Comment: Well, you answer my question about how to solve the integral. I thought that I understod this part but clearly I didn't and since I already verified your answer I thought I could just make a new question about this specifically. There was nothing wrong with you answer.

Comment: What you do not understand is that $|e^{i z}|$ is **not** less than or equal to $1$.  Remember $z=R e^{i \theta}$ on the circular arc so that $$e^{i z} = e^{i R \cos{\theta}} e^{-R \sin{\theta}}$$  Please reread my solution.

Comment: It isn't? We have that $\left| e^z \right|=e^{Re z}$ so that gives us $\left| e^{iz}\right| = \left| e^{ix-y}\right| = e^{-y}$ and in the upper half plane that is  less than or equal to 1? I think it way my professor that showed me this. Maybe I misunderstood him. 

I did the final exam yesterday but I think i'm going to do it again after christmas so i better get this straight.

Comment: Right, it is in this case, but not necessarily.  You should see that it is not less than one when $\sin{\theta} \lt 0$, for example.  This is why we stick to a semicircle in the upper half plane.  But you still have to carry out the operations involving the integral over theta as I showed in that previous solution.

Comment: Yes, I think that I understand! Thank you for the clarifications :) Now i'm off to differential equations, exam on monday!