# Evaluate the integral $ \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^2 - 1}}{{x^2 + 1}}\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx} $

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

So I have an assignement to do and it has multiple integrals, I did all of them but this one I can't seem to know how to do it.

$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{x^2  - 1}}{{x^2  + 1}}\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx} 
$$

I mean don't get me wrong I tried a lot of methodes that I know of, also I tried every app that has step by step solving but nothing seems to work, if any could help me with this problem and provied a little explanation I'd appreciate it.
If this question is a duplicate please provied me with a link.

Comment: You say you tried a lot of methods- which? It is very important you show and explain what you have done since that saves us from wasting our time on failed methods, and it betters allows us to constructively help you. E.g. are you allowed to use the residue theorem? Or are you only allowed series methods? Do you know Dirichlet’s integral?

Answer (score 4):

A method using the Laplace transform.
Use the property that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} (\mathcal{L} f)(y)\cdot(\mathcal{L}^{-1} g)(y)\,dy$$
Setting $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x(x^2+1)}$, we have:
$$(\mathcal{L} f)(y)=\frac{1}{1+y^2}$$
$$(\mathcal{L}^{-1} g)(y)=2\cos (y)-1$$

Hence $$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(x^2-1)\sin x}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx &= 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (y)}{1+y^2}\,dy-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+y^2}\,dy\\&=\left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\pi \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Write
$$\frac{x^2-1}{x \left(x^2+1\right)}=\frac{(x-1) (x+1)}{x (x-i) (x+i)}$$ Use partial fraction decomposition and you will face antiderivatives
$$I_k=\int \frac {\sin(x)}{x+k}\,dx$$ Using a quite obious change of variable and basic trigonometric will give the antiderivative and then the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Use [$ \int_0^{ \infty } \frac{x\sin x}{{x^2  + 1}}dx
= \frac{\pi}{2e} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1492726/686284) to obtain
$$
\int_0^{ \infty } {\frac{{x^2  - 1}}{{x^2  + 1}}\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx} 
= \int_0^{ \infty }{\frac{2x\sin x}{{x^2  + 1}}-\frac{{\sin x}}{x}\ dx} 
= \frac{\pi}{e}-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$